# Append part of the audio at the end of another audio

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

With audio files A and B:

A : `|--- Some content ---|--- Extra content --- |`

B : `|--- Some content ---|`

Assume the end of B is where the start of the extra content in A.

I want to append that extra content at the end of B.

Can I achieve this with some command line programs, such as ffmpeg?

Comment: Do you know the duration of B? Do the files have the same format/codec properties?

Comment: I think I could get the duration of B with some methods. A and B may or maybe in different codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the duration of B is X (in seconds), you would use

```
ffmpeg -i A -i B -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='lt(t,X)'[a];[a][1]amix=duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2" out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i playlist.txt $OTHER_OPTIONS
```

In playlist.txt, write this:

```
file 'B'
file 'A'
inpoint <start_of_extra_content>
```

Would you like to know [more](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1)?